# Read/write Person metadata from a Word doc stored in SharePoint using VBA or VSTO?

Tags: sharepoint, vba, ms-office, vsto

Scenario: Document library in SharePoint with column x of "Person or Group" type.  From within a VBA macro (or VSTO add-in) we're trying to access the MetaProperty on the document to set/get the user name.  Any attempt to access the value via the ContentTypeProperties collection throws a

> Type MisMatch error (13).

The Type property of the MetaProperty object says it's `msoMetaPropertyTypeUser`.  I cannot find any examples of how to work with MetaProperties of this type.  Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do something like this:

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yoursite/subsite"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["DocLibraryName"];
            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(list.Views["All Documents"]);
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                item["Modified By"] = "Updated Value";
            }
        }
    }
```

Any metadata for a document should be available by indexing the column name of the SPListItem.

Comment: In order to be able to define a variable of type SPSite, where do I find the dll that I need to reference first?

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.  It should be in the GAC on a machine with SharePoint installed.  I have also found a copy of it in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI folder.

Answer (score 1):

I did it.

The trick here is actually to know that if you put a string corresponding to the user index in MOSS users in the custom property of the Word document, MOSS will recognize it and find the corresponding user to map the field.

so you just need to call http:///_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx
use the function GetUserInfo and retrieve the user index (ID) from it.

```
MOSSusergroup.UserGroup userGroupService = new MOSSusergroup.UserGroup();
userGroupService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
System.Xml.XmlNode node = userGroupService.GetUserInfo(userLogin);
string index = node.FirstChild.Attributes["ID"].Value;
```